# iOS How to draw text in UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uivewcontroller

I'm feeling very stupid right now.

I'm trying to draw text onto a UIViewController.

I'm using Xcode 5 and started with a simple Single Page project, and have done nothing else except adding this code to the ViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    CGRect myRect=CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.size.width,self.view.bounds.size.height);
    UIFont *myFont=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:50];

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

    NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [attributes setObject:myFont forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
    [attributes setObject:paragraphStyle forKey:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName];
    [attributes setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:4] forKey:NSStrokeWidthAttributeName];
    [attributes setObject:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:NSStrokeColorAttributeName];
    [@"test" drawInRect:myRect withAttributes:attributes];

    // draw fill
    [attributes removeObjectForKey:NSStrokeWidthAttributeName];
    [attributes removeObjectForKey:NSStrokeColorAttributeName];
    [attributes setObject:[UIColor blackColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
    [@"test" drawInRect:myRect withAttributes:attributes];
}
```

It runs without errors but produces no text - why?

Comment: Are you just doing this as an exercise for learning (good for you if so)?  Otherwise, you can just put a `UILabel` in the view and let that take care of drawing your text.

Comment: Yes, trying to learn - I've had troubles with UILabels cropping the Descenders off fonts,so I thought I'd see if I could draw the text myself and eliminate the problems.

Answer (score 0):

The `drawInRect` method doesn't work with `UIViewController`. That method is a `UIView` method and will only work if your class is a `UIView` class or subclass.

So, as mentioned above, you can just set your text attributes on a UILabel and display them wherever you like on the screen. It should give you the same effect. Optionally, you could try to change the subclass to `UIView`, but that could require more modifications to your code than you would like.

Comment: So if I wanted to use the automatically created View in my UIViewController that would work? If so, how would I use the Rect in the View? Or can I add an ImageView?

Comment: I've had no luck using the automatically created view such as `self.view`, or a `UIImageView` with the `drawInRect` method. You can do some drawing on a `UIImageView` with Core Graphics, but that is probably not what you are looking for with drawing text.

Answer (score 0):

To add to tfrank377, you can add labels programmatically with something like

```
   UILabel *addLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 30)];
   [self.view addSubview:addLabel];
   addLabel.text = @"Hello World";
```

which will display text on your UIView.

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying something besides UILabels due to other errors described above.

Comment: Can you give an example of a descender being cut off?

Comment: Sure - here's another question I've asked. Note that the point is not to shrink the font until the problem goes away - the point is to display the largest font possible...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22897158/fonts-not-fitting-properly-in-uilabel-ascender-or-descender-cropped